# Elasticsearch nested query IP address and honeypot

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I query ElasticSearch to find if one IP address occurred >= 10 times per day and it was related to >= 3 t-pot_hostname values?

Following query doesn't provide what I want to achieve.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "ip": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "src_ip.keyword",
        "min_doc_count": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "t-pot": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "t-pot_hostname.keyword",
            "min_doc_count": 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-1d"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```

Query output provide src_ip and t-pot_hostname buckets.

```
"aggregations": {
    "ip": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 5427,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 264226,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "10.10.100.203",
          "doc_count": 954982,
          "t-pot": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "tpot3",
                "doc_count": 1788
              }
            ]
          }
        },
```

Comment: What result do you get and what result do you expect instead? Also, what is the mapping of your `src_ip` field?

Comment: I get aggregated src_ip bucket and aggregated t-pot_hostname bucket. I want to check if src_ip value occurred more than 10 times and if that src_ip value related to 3 or more t-pot_hostname values.

Comment: That I know, you already explained it in your question. My questions were "what result do you get instead?" and "what is the mapping of `src_ip`?"

Comment: "aggregations": {
        "ip": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 5427,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 264226,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "10.10.100.203",
              "doc_count": 954982,
              "t-pot": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                  {
                    "key": "tpot3",
                    "doc_count": 1788
                  }

Comment: You should update your question with that information as it's more legible